# Detecting coplanarity by given pairwise distances

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Given a 3D point set $P$, where $|P| \gg 4$ is there a way other than using [Cayley-Menger determinant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-MengerDeterminant.html) to detect if a group of points are coplanar or not?

In other words, what are the methods to extract coplanar point groups in a given set of points and pairwise distances (not the coordinates)?

If not, is there a proof that we cannot detect coplanarity without having all pairwise distances between each four nodes in $P$?

Comment: "to detect if a group of points are coplanar"? the group if a subset (if so, well, 3 points are always coplanar) or the full set? Or you mean any 4-points subset?

Comment: @leonbloy I see that the question was ambiguous. I corrected it. Thanks for your notice.

Comment: I still find the question unclear. Do you have exactly four points, or more than that?

Comment: @Semiclassical corrected that as well. $|P|$ is around 1000.

Comment: The algorithm you are looking for may be computationally very expensive. If all you thousand points lie on the boundary of a convex body in $\mathbb{R}$, are you expecting to have about $333$ groups of coplanar points or the complete almost billion?

Comment: In the first case, just take an arbitrary triple of points and complete it with all the coplanar points in your set, putting them away. Then take a new triple of points and continue till no points are left to place. In the second case, life is hard.